# Recycle an application pool using a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, iis-7.5

I want to recycle my application pool using one-liner command which I can put in my PowerShell script.  I added the following code in my PowerShell script:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$site = "Default Web Site"

$pool = (Get-Item "IIS:\Sites\$site"| Select-Object applicationPool).applicationPool

Restart-WebAppPool $pool
```

But I am getting an error that name [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) doesn't exist. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please ignore my above comment as I am unable to edit it. Following is what I want to say:                                                                                   I added the following code in my powershell script: 

Restart-WebItem 'IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool'  

Import-Module WebAdministration
$site = "Default Web Site"
$pool = (Get-Item "IIS:\Sites\$site"| Select-Object applicationPool).applicationPool
Restart-WebAppPool $pool                                                                          But I get error that name IIS doesn't exist. I am unable to figure it out

Comment: I'd recommend editing your question, rather than adding comments. That's generally how folks do it here at StackOverflow. Check out the "How to ask" article, too: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for the advise Trevor.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Short and simple, like this...

```
Restart-WebAppPool (Get-Website -Name <YourSiteName>).applicationPool
```

Comment: Does this recycle or restart? I believe those are two different things

Comment: For application pool this is the same. New process will be created and new memory allocated. Where and why you should restart app pool, and when it must be recycling?)

Comment: Description on msdn says - this command causes the specified application pool to be recycled.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`appcmd.exe`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200(v=ws.10).aspx):

```
appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name:'MyAppPool'
```

---

You can also retrieve the corresponding [WMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) instance and invoke the `Recycle()` method:

```
$myAppPool = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\WebAdministration -Class ApplicationPool -Filter "Name = 'MyAppPool'"
$myAppPool.Recycle()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I want to achieve it through powershell script because I am performing other tasks too along with recycling.

Comment: The syntax is incorrect - it should be `/apppool.name:'MyAppPool'` with a colon, not equals.

Answer (score 4):

This may work:

```
Write-Host "App Pool Recycling Started...."
& $env:windir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list apppools /state:Started /xml | & $env:windir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd recycle apppools /in 
Write-Host "App Pool Recycling Completed"
```

It works for me in [AWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) through the *Run* command.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

$site = "MySite"
$pool = (Get-Item "IIS:\Sites\$site"| Select-Object applicationPool).applicationPool

#Recycle the application pool:
Restart-WebAppPool $pool
```

Comment: please add some explanation about your proposed solution. You can read [how to write good answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42442173/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: OK, the OP seems to have left the building (*"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*). Perhaps somebody else can reverse engineer it and provide some information (preferably by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42442173/edit), not here comments) - but \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\* ***without*** \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\* any kind of ***meta information*** like "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today. Use the ***edit summary*** (or comments) to describe and justify the change.

Answer (score 3):

The following command works for me

```
invoke-command -computername servername -scriptblock {C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe recycle apppool "apppoolname"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `WebAdministration` is old and badly supported under PowerShell 7, here's an updated answer using the fresher [`IISAdministration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/?view=windowsserver2019-ps) module:

```
Import-Module IISAdministration
$pool = Get-IISAppPool -Name "DefaultAppPool"
$pool.Recycle()
```

You can also do this as a two-liner, or even one-liner if you import the module in your profile:

```
Import-Module IISAdministration
(Get-IISAppPool("DefaultAppPool")).Recycle()
```

Do note that accessing the IISServerManager object requires administrative permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't run all PowerShell scripts as administrator - it's dangerous.

But *appcmd.exe* is not available unless running in an administrator prompt.

This command line will prompt for elevation if you're running in a regular, un-elevated prompt:

```
Start-Process c:\windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe "recycle apppool /apppool.name:MyAppPool" -Verb RunAs
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you need to recycle all the Application Pools:

```
 Import-Module IISAdministration

 Get-IISAppPool | ForEach-Object{ if($_.State -eq "Started"){ $_.Recycle() } }
```

*If the AppPool is stopped it will throw an exception*

Answer (score 0):

Use the -Name option:

```
IIS:\> Restart-WebAppPool -Name "DefaultAppPool"
```