# How To Populate Shutdown Executable field in IIS App Pool through Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

In Internet Information Services Manager, for each app pool, there is an option to set path to a Shutdown Executable, and any parameters under `Rapid-Fail Protection` in advanced settings.

I have several app pools (a couple hundred) and would like to use a PowerShell script to automate setting
the shutdown field of each one to a program I created.

Does such a PowerShell command exist? I have pored through the appropriate documentation but with no results.

[image: The Field in Question]

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far ??

Comment: The closest I could find was recycling the application (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311797/recycle-application-pool-using-powershell-script) but that is a separate command.

I was wondering if there is a similar command but for the shutdown, I was not able to find any in the available documentation on the Microsoft Website

Answer (score 0):

Short answer? I cant figure it out in Powershell specifically, However.. using "appcmd.exe" I was able to make this happen.  I wrote a script that tried to restart the app pool and emails me the result. This script gets kicked off by the rapid fail protection. I can share this script too if you like... 
However, I really didnt want to manually set every app pool as you mention, so I came up with the following.. Its not as pretty or elegant as some, but, it works:

```
$poolList = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\*").name

ForEach($pool in $poolList) {
    C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set apppool "$pool" /Failure.autoshutdownParams:"D:\_Scripts\CheckPools.ps1 -PoolName $pool"
    C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set apppool "$pool" /Failure.autoshutdownexe:"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
    Get-ItemProperty -Path "IIS:\AppPools\$pool" -name Failure.autoshutdownexe|select *
}
```

I can confirm for me, with Windows 2016, this script sets the Shutdown Executable, and the Shutdown Executable Parameter.  The Executable is set to launch powershell, and the parameters calls a powershell script and passes it the app pool name.