# How to Trigger Recycle with MSBuild?

Tags: iis, msbuild

I use MSBuild to publish a project to a website using the file system. Is there a way to trigger a recycle? It appears that sometimes this causes the Integration Tests to fail depending on the changes because a recycle is not done. This is the web client project but we have additional projects with the exact command used the same way for the project. We are using IIS 8+. This is done VIA command line, any alternatives, maybe edit the web.config manually VIA command line after the MSBuild publish?

```
"%SOAB_MSBUILD_EXE%" "%SOAB_LOCAL_APP_PATH%\WebClient\WebClients.csproj"  /p:Configuration=Debug /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /p:Platform=AnyCPU /t:WebPublish /p:WebPublishMethod=FileSystem /p:DeleteExistingFiles=True /p:publishUrl=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CI\WebClient
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: If your goal is merely for testing, calling iisreset would be much simpler.

Comment: I wish I could but IIS is shared. Wish it wasn't this way but we have limited resources and senior Dev doesn't want to change it. In my opinion CI environments should be standalone.

Comment: Then call PowerShell, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38311797/recycle-application-pool-using-powershell-script or appcmd.